# How to pass json data into next activity and from next activity i want to pass it to a fragment?

Tags: android

```
username = editText_name.getText().toString() ;
                password = editText_password.getText().toString();

                request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jsonObject.names().get(1).equals("data")){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Logged IN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

//here i am assigning data to username and details to password

```
                                username = jsonObject.getString("data");
                                password = jsonObject.getString("details");
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dashboard.class);
```

//as i debug hre username is returning null

```
                                intent.putExtra("username",username);
                                intent.putExtra("password",password);
                                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: In the other activity are you getting the values?

Comment: Like this. 
`String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username","defaultKey");`

Comment: username and password is null?

Comment: Could you show your json code ?

Comment: Are you sure you get your `data` and `details` to `username` and `password` ? Just debug it.

Comment: From where you get values of username and password that you are passing to intent ? I dont see any values assigning to username and password obtained from your json or any where else. please show complete code of your activity so I can help you out. happy coding :)

Comment: json code is correct , the problem hre is i m not able to display the data into next activity and frm next activity into a fragment

Comment: try getIntent().getExtras().get("username") only

Answer (score 0):

```
username = editText_name.getText().toString() ;
                password = editText_password.getText().toString();

                request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jsonObject.names().get(1).equals("data")){
                                /*to pass data to the next activity*/
                               username = jsonObject.getString("data");
                            password = jsonObject.getString("details");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dashboard.class);

                            startActivity(intent);
                            intent.putExtra("username",username);
                            intent.putExtra("password",password);
                            startActivity(intent);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Successfully Logged IN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

on next activity fetch data

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
String pass = getIntent().getStringExtra("details");
```

/*now pass it to fragment */

```
FragmentX f = new FragmentX();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putExtra("username",name);
b.putExtra("details",pass);
f.setArguments(b);
```

/*now in onCreate method of fragment*/

```
Bundle b = getArguments();
String name = b.getStringExtra("username");
String pass = b.getStringExtra("details");
```

snap shot to the onCreate() method
[image: like this]

Comment: );

//this is my Activity

username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
        password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password"

        FirstFragment f = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("username",username);
        b.putString("password",password);
        f.setArguments(b);

Comment: //this is my fragment , i m not getting any ERROR bt data is not seen in the fragment 

Bundle b = getArguments();
            musername = b.getString("username");
            mpassword = b.getString("password");

        if(musername != null && mpassword != null){

            mname.setText("" +mpassword);
            mid.setText("" +musername);

        }

Comment: in fragment on which method you are calling getArguments();?

Comment: inside onCreateView

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
         mname=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_next_screen);
        mid=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_next_screen);
Bundle b = getArguments();
            musername = b.getString("username");
            mpassword = b.getString("password");
if(musername != null && mpassword != null){
            mname.setText("" +mpassword);
            mid.setText("" +musername);}

Comment: no you need to override the mothod onCreate and then getArguments() in onCreate method not in onCreateView() method.

Comment: n in wch method should v initialize the id's of text fields

Comment: in onCreateView method

Comment: i have updated the answer for you you can see initialize the views in onCreateView method as shown in image

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.mohamedhidayath.campusk12.FirstFragment.onCreate(FirstFragment.java:41)

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle b = getArguments();
        musername = b.getString("username");
        mpassword = b.getString("password");
    }

Comment: Nouman cn i hv ur mail id if dnt mind so tht i cn explain u exactly wt i want.